# How to force PythonScriptStep to run in Azure ML

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, pipeline, azure-machine-learning-service, azuremlsdk

I'm relatively new to Azure ML and trying to run a model via PythonScriptStep

I can publish pipelines and run the model.  However, once it has run once I can't re-submit the step as it states "This run reused the output from a previous run".

My code declares allow_reuse to be False, but this doesn't seem to make a difference and I can simply not resubmit the step even though the underlying data is changing.

```
train_step = PythonScriptStep(
        name='model_train',
        script_name="model_train.py",
        compute_target=aml_compute,
        runconfig=pipeline_run_config,
        source_directory=train_source_dir,
        allow_reuse=False)
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Have you also tried forcing the output regeneration for all steps by setting `regenerate_outputs=True` while submitting the pipeline for the first time as stated here? [Create and run machine learning pipelines with Azure Machine Learning SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/v1/how-to-create-machine-learning-pipelines#:~:text=Force%20output%20regeneration%20for%20all%20steps%20in%20a%20run%20with%20pipeline_run%20%3D%20exp.submit(pipeline%2C%20regenerate_outputs%3DTrue))